# Horizontal Alignment with Pseudoelement

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to create a sass mixin that justifies all child divs horizontally. I'd prefer the html to look something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
</div>
```

If I put a `<span>` element after all of the divs, then it works fine, but when I try to replace it with an 'after' pseudo-element, then the last element is off by a few pixels.

```
@mixin spread-wrapper() {
  text-align: justify;
  -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
  text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
  position: relative;

  &:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
  }

  > * {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
```

You can see both the working (with span) and non-working (with pseudo-element) over at http://jsfiddle.net/jeffaudio/Sun4b/

Why aren't the two methods acting the same?

Update: They look the same in Firefox, but are different in both Chrome 28 and Safari 6.

Comment: Note that you can't use the `content` property on elements other than the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements - I also don't notice *any* difference between the two examples.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle to remove the content property since it wasn't being used. I did notice they only seem to be different in Chrome / Safari. They look identical in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by whitespace.  All you have to do is remove the whitespace after the last item.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sun4b/8/

```
<div class="wrapperA">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div><!--
--></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I came across [this tutorial](http://code.jelmerdemaat.nl/2012/perfectly-justified-css-grid-technique-using-inline-block/) which I assume is the one you based your code on and after running some tests I found that setting `font-size:0` to the wrapper and overriding it in the children is what makes the difference.

Here's the updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Sun4b/7/

Comment: Setting the font-size to 0 is the worst way to deal with undesirable whitespace since it cannot be used with relative font-sizes.